# Get Country name from Timezone in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, localization, timezone, locale

I am implementing in my swing application something like, my Country drop-down should automatically get selected with the system Country (Country selected within the Operating System) on form load.

I am facing a strange problem of not getting the proper country name from Locale object. The Locale details when I am running the code from any of my system always shows en-US (though the language in my system is English(en) the country it should show IN (India) instead of US).

Then after I thought of getting Country name using the `TimeZone` object, so is there any way of getting the Country name from `TimeZone` object? I am running under Windows 7 OS, my Region and Language settings does shows India as my country and English as my language. So what could be the solution to this problem? How can we get the Country name from `TimeZone` or through any other means using any other Java class (the condition, it should provide with the Country of your Operating System- the country being specified in Region and Language settings).

Comment: What does `System.getProperty("user.country");` return on that machine? On this machine (in Australia) I see `AU`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The System.getProperty is also returning me the same thing (US here, though I am in India right now). I don't know what setting inside my system is getting me the US output, my concern is, suppose I am using the application from Germany, then how can I get Germany as my system language using TimeZone object or some other means ? To be straight with, I want the name of the country from where the application is being used, from within the system itself. Please help.

Comment: Iirc, `user.country` is derived from the language setting. Since there are usually multiple countries within a time zone, I don't see a way of pinpointing the actual country. The country settings are usually used to determine the time zone and language, but for obvious reasons reasons this can't be done vice versa.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg then is there any other way around through which we can fetch the country of the system i.e. the country being specified in Regional Setting within the control panel (here talking about Regional Setting of Windows Operating System)? The concern is to get the country of that system on which the swing application is being executed. Any workaround in your knowledge base if any ?

Comment: @VinitSharma: Not really. In WebApplications, I tend to set the country as an init param. Sometimes I have a mapping based on the domain, e.g. myapp.de maps to Germany and myapp.com maps to USA. Depends on your use case, really. You might want to rephrase your question accordingly and write a new question.